# Is this if statement redundant or not?

Tags: c#, string

When I was looking at [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method implementation, I saw a for loop like this:

```
public static string Join(string separator, params object[] values)
{
  ...
  for (int index = 1; index < values.Length; ++index)
  {
    sb.Append(separator);
    if (values[index] != null) // first if statement
    {
      string str2 = values[index].ToString(); 
      if (str2 != null)  // second if statement
        sb.Append(str2);
    }
  }
  ...
 }
```

Here, second if statement seems redundant to me.I thought if `values[index] != null` is **true** then how could be `values[index].ToString() == null` **true** ? As far as I know `ToString` always has to be return something, right ? Even if the type doesn't override `ToString` method it should return Type's *fully qualified name* (Namespace + Class name).So when I see it in .NET Framework source code, I thought maybe there is a reason and I'm missing something.If there is a reason, what is it ?

Comment: I suppose you could implement ToString and return null

Comment: You could go a step further and get rid of `if (values[index] != null)`, too.  Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5atxc566.aspx), "The Append(Object) method calls the Object.ToString method to get the string representation of value. If value is null, no changes are made to the StringBuilder object." So, the inner loop could have been replaced with `sb.Append(separator); sb.Append(values[index]);` Mind you, there may be minuscule performance differences between the two approaches.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Technically it’s not redundant, as it’s possible that an object’s `ToString` implementation returns `null`. Of course that’s not really useful and custom types shouldn’t do that.

Practically in your case however, the check is redundant because `StringBuilder` is fine when the argument to `Append` is `null`. It will then just append nothing:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("A");
sb.Append((string) null);
sb.Append("B");

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString() == "AB"); // true
```

Comment: `Append` has a similar null check in it's implementation, [defense in depth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_in_depth_(computing)) I guess

Answer (score 12):

I suppose you could override `ToString` and return null.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return null;
}
```